# Implementing PushPlugin for iOS with Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode5, plist, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm working on implementing push notifications in my `Phonegap` iOS application, and a few things are a bit confusing.

First, i'm following this tutorial here: http://devgirl.org/2012/10/19/tutorial-apple-push-notifications-with-phonegap-part-1/

Her tutorials tend to be straightforward, but in one step, she mentions looking under the resources folder and accessing the "`Cordova.plist`" file, adding something under the Plugin Key.

As I am unable to do this step, the next step (involving modification of the `AppDelegate.m` file) produces multiple errors that I feel might be connected to this. I understand from reading the comments on her tutorial and doing some research that after version 2.5 or so of `Cordova`, there is no longer a `Cordova.plist` file, and it instead has been converted to the `config.xml` file only.

My config.xml file has this feature added:

```
<feature name="PushPlugin">
  <param name="ios-package" value="PushPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Is there some other place that I might be able to add the plugin key and value since I don't have a Cordova.plist file? I'm pretty new to Xcode and Objective-C, so any suggestions or explanations are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you are following is some what out of date.

I would suggest using this plugin:

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

This plugin is very well documented and supports automatic installation via plugman.  Manually installing a push notification plugin for iOS is very complicated and a nightmare to maintain if you need to scrap your project.

Take a look at the documentation and get yourself familiar with plugman before using the plugin linked above.

All that is required to install the plugin is this following command:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
```

You then must write a few JavaScript functions to interface with the plugin, it is all very clearly documented in the readme.MD.

Comment: thank you so much - it's such a pain trying to figure out how relevant these Cordova tutorials are, it seems like so much changes from version to version. A quick question about Plugman - Assuming I navigate to my project directory in terminal and run the above command, do I have any risk of losing html/js files already in my application's "www" folder?

Comment: No, installing a plugin through plugman will not touch the www or merges folder, only the plugins folder.

Comment: Too bad they made different register functions for each platform, instead of a single register function that determines the platform and acts accordingly.